# Why is the auxiliary field saddle point space independent in sigma models?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, sigma-models

I am followint https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157384900218.
Consider the sigma model in 2 dimensional Euclidean space with action
$$
S[\sigma^a,\alpha]=\frac{1}{2}\int d^2x\bigg[\partial_{\mu}\sigma^a\partial^{\mu}\sigma^a-\frac{\alpha}{N^{1/2}}(\sigma^a\sigma^a-\frac{N}{f})\bigg].
$$
With this we have the generating functional is
$$
Z[J^a]=\int d\sigma d\alpha\exp(-S[\sigma^a,\alpha]+\int d^x J^a\sigma^a)
$$
The $\sigma$ integral can be done "completing the square" and we are left with
$$
Z[J^a]=\int d\alpha\exp\bigg(-S_{eff}[\alpha]+\frac{1}{2}\int d^2xJ^a[\frac{1}{-\partial^2+\alpha*N^{-1/2}}]J^a\bigg)
$$
where
$$
S_{eff}[\alpha]=\frac{N}{2}Tr\log(-\partial^2+\frac{\alpha}{N^{1/2}})-\int d^x\frac{N^{1/2}}{2f}\alpha
$$
At this point the authors claim that the remaining $\alpha$ integral can be evaluated using the saddle point technique and that the saddle point $\alpha_{saddle}(x)$ is $x$ independent because of Lorentz invariance . Obviously there is no Lorentz invariance since we are in Eucliean space, so I will assume here they meant rotational invariance instead. Even then, how does this follow? Why does rotational invariance in $\mathbb{R}^2$  imply that this stationary point is space independent?

Comment: The system is translation invariant and there is no spontaneous breaking of continuous symmetries in two dimensions.